# Need help with SQL aggregation query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, data-warehouse

What is the most straightforward approach to producing a data set that can be used in a SQL Server Reporting Services report to display the following:

```
SalesPerson        # Sales        # Gross        Profit
John Doe               100       $140,000       $25,000
Everyone Else (Avg.)  1200     $2,000,000      $250,000


Jane Smith              80       $100,000       $15,000
Everyone Else (Avg.)  1220     $2,040,000      $260,000


...and so on.
```

This is a very, very simplified example of what I'm trying to do (for instance, the real scenario involves showing the 'Everyone Else' broken out into three categorical rows), but it illustrates the primary objective of displaying aggregate data for each individual with a comparison to everyone else (exclusive). Pseudo-code would be fine. My first stab at the SQL code for this got pretty tangled pretty quickly, and I know there must be a more direct method.

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the ability to use SSAS.  It has some facilities that make this pretty easy

Comment: Getting the info is easy, it's formatting it in the layout you provided that would be a pain.  Usually the grand totals & calculations are only displayed at the end of the resultset.

Comment: +1 to Ponies' comment.  SQL is not the right tool for formatting output.

Comment: @ DrewM - Actually this is running against the data mart upon which a SSAS cube is based. Which facilities specifically are you thinking of, as I didn't have much luck making it work from SSAS.

Comment: Oh, and I'm not so much interested in SQL Server formatting the output (SSRS would handle that). I just need a result set that would facilitate that report display.

Comment: Regarding the option of using SSAS, I have done so with other reports, and that would very well be a solution here, but I have been unable to figure out how to produce the exclusionary aggregations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not mind formatting later, then if we assume you have something like:

[image: sales_model_02]

First I'll need some helper variables for total counts

```
/* Few helper variables*/
DECLARE @TotalQuantity int
       ,@TotalAmount decimal(19, 4)
       ,@TotalProfit decimal(19, 4)
       ,@EveryoneElse int
```

Then we fetch total for everyone in a given period (YEAR = 2009)

```
/* Fetch totals in the period*/
SELECT  @TotalQuantity = sum(SalesQuantity)
       ,@TotalAmount = sum(SalesAmount)
       ,@TotalProfit = sum(Profit)
       ,@EveryoneElse = count(DISTINCT SalesPersonKey) - 1
FROM   factSales AS s
       JOIN dimDate AS d ON s.DateKey = d.DateKey
WHERE   [Year] = 2009

/* Now we have totals for everyone in the period */
```

And now for each person vs everyone else, but all in one row.

```
/* Totals for each sales person vs everyone else Average */
SELECT  FullName
       ,SUM(SalesQuantity) AS [PersonSalesCount]
       ,SUM(SalesAmount) AS [PersonSalesAmount]
       ,SUM(Profit) AS [PersonSalesProfit]
       ,( @TotalQuantity - SUM(SalesQuantity) ) / @EveryoneElse AS [EveryoneElseAvgSalesCount]
       ,( @TotalAmount - SUM(SalesAmount) ) / @EveryoneElse AS [EveryoneElseAvgSalesAmount]
       ,( @TotalProfit - SUM(Profit) ) / @EveryoneElse AS [EveryoneElseAvgSalesProfit]
FROM    factSales AS s
        JOIN dimDate AS d ON s.DateKey = d.DateKey
        RIGHT JOIN dimSalesPerson AS p ON p.SalesPersonKey = s.SalesPersonKey
WHERE   [Year] = 2009
GROUP BY FullName
```

Now you can package all this in a stored procedure with parameter(s) for date interval. May still need to tweak number of sales people to determine which were active in a certain period and how to count those who did not sell anything. With this, `EveryoneElse` means number of sales people who sold something -1; so if you have 10 sales people and only 5 sold something, than `EveryoneElse = 4`.

Comment: This works great, when all salespeople are considered in one category. How would you tweak it to provide aggregate comparisons through a three-level hierarchy (person vs. branch, person vs. region, person vs. country)?

Comment: Providing that the person is in the branch, region, country -- `WHERE   [Year] = 2009 AND [Region] = 'North'`, or `WHERE   [Year] = 2009 AND [Country] = 'Canada'`; essentially filter on branch, region, country.

Comment: Thanks, Damir. Right you are, that would give me what I need for a single person. I was actually thinking in terms of running the result set for multiple people at once. I'm not sure how easily it would be to work that grouping in. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure I understand, would give you for all of them (one row per person) relative to everyone else in region/country. For group of people, like store, replace FullName by StoreName, and include store in joins.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly not very performant, but declaratively clear:

```
declare @i int = 0
declare @j int = 1

select * from
(
select (@i = @i + 2) as order_col, SalesPerson, sales, gross, profit
from myTable order by SalesPerson

union all

select (@j = @j + 2) as order_col, 'Everybody else'
, (select sum(sales) from myTable i where i.SalesPerson <> o.Salesperson)
, (select sum(gross) from myTable i where i.SalesPerson <> o.Salesperson)
, (select sum(profit) from myTable i where i.SalesPerson <> o.Salesperson)
from myTable o
order by SalesPerson
) x order by order_col
```

(The second part of the `UNION` can definitely be improved, but it's late and I can't think straight..)

Answer (score 0):

In SSRS, put an extra detail row in your table. Then use the Scope parameter on aggregate functions, and do the average from first principles.

Eg:

```
(Sum(Fields!Sales.Value, "table1") - Fields!Sales.Value) 
/
(Sum(Fields!NumSales.Value, "table1") - Fields!NumSales.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am making some assumptions here but if you have a table like so

```
If object_id('Sales') is not null 
  Drop table Sales

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sales]
(
 [Salesperson] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [Sales] [int] NULL,
 [Gross] [money] NULL,
 [Profit] [money] NULL,
)
```

That is populated with Data like so

```
Insert into Sales values ('John Doe', 100, 200.00, 100.00)
Insert into Sales values ('John Doe', 125, 300.00, 100.00)
Insert into Sales values ('Jane Smith', 100, 200.00, 100.00)
Insert into Sales values ('Jane Smith', 125, 1.00, 0.50)
Insert into Sales values ('Joel Spolsky', 100, 2.00, 1.00)
Insert into Sales values ('Joel Spolsky', 125, 3.00, 1.00)
```

Then a stored procedure like so may give you what you are looking for

```
If object_id('usp_SalesReport') is not null 
Drop procedure usp_SalesReport

Go


Create Procedure usp_SalesReport
as
Declare @results as table
(
 SalesPerson nvarchar(50),
 Sales int,
 Gross money,
 Profit money
)

Declare  @SalesPerson nvarchar(50)
Declare SalesSums CURSOR FOR

Select  distinct SalesPerson from Sales

Open SalesSums

Fetch SalesSums INTO @SalesPerson

While @@Fetch_Status = 0

Begin
 Insert into @results Select Sales.Salesperson, sum(sales), sum(Gross), sum(profit) from Sales group by Sales.Salesperson having Sales.Salesperson = @SalesPerson
 Insert into @results Select 'EveryoneElse', avg(sales), avg(Gross), avg(profit) from Sales where Salesperson <> @SalesPerson

Fetch SalesSums INTO @SalesPerson          
End
Select * from @results
Close SalesSums
Deallocate SalesSums
Return
```